# Re-route to a different subview based on language

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, routes

I wrote an app with angular.js and trying to load different subviews based on the page they land on. Specifically, when the user is landing on the english version a partial view is loaded and when they land on the french version a different one is loaded. But whatever I'm not seeing in my code makes the subview always land on the ELSE (or '/') route. This is the current code in my appRoutes.js file...

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

var homeLang = document.documentElement.getAttribute('lang');
var english = 'en';

var homeView = function (homeLang) {

    if (homeLang === english) {
         homeView = '/';
         return homeView;
        } else {

        homeView = '/accueil';
        return homeView;
    }
};

$routeProvider

    // client routes

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })

    .when('/web', {
        templateUrl: 'views/web.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })

    .when('/design', {
        templateUrl: 'views/design.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })

    .when('/hosting', {
        templateUrl: 'views/hosting.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })

    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })

    .when('/accueil', {
        templateUrl: 'views/accueil.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })

    .when('/sites', {
        templateUrl: 'views/sites.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })

    .when('/services', {
        templateUrl: 'views/services.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })

    .when('/hebergement', {
        templateUrl: 'views/hebergement.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })

    .when('/contactez', {
        templateUrl: 'views/contactez.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })

    .otherwise({ redirectTo: homeView });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

Here is the HTML that loads the different views.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
<div class="container">
  <div role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/accueil">Accueil</a></li>
          <li><a href="/sites">Sites & Apps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/services">Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="/hebergement">Hébergement</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contactez">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
      </div></div></div></div></div>
 <section class="content">
<div ng-view></div></section></body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually went back to the code and used ui-router instead and created states with building blocks (several views) and it solved all my issues!! :)

Comment: Can you please share your solution. I also need it. I cant figure it out

Answer (score 0):

in your view, you can load a different template based on language without changing routing.
for example have in the routed view something like


than you can also add a ng-if before each span to check the language value.

Comment: sorry code was deleted - i wrote <span ng-include src="'my-english-template.html'"> and <span ng-include src="'my-english-template.html'">

Comment: I would usually do this but in my HTML file I have ng-view to load the other pages after. Some of the routes in my code above belong to the french version and some other to the english version. Can I setup a default view in ng-view upon loading? Then as we click on the navigation it loads different views. I added the HTML above.

Comment: when you first login, i guess you are on '/' which means that your default route it .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })

Comment: Yes so I need to default "/" when it is the menu is the english version, but when the menu is the french version I need to default  to "/accueil"...which is what I'm trying to achieve with my conditional. The conditional seems to work however the value homeLang doesn't seem like it's picking it up within my appRoute.js file and therefore always defaults to "/accueil". Just to visualize my structure its: language selection(regular html) - to - angular app where the menu is in the language of selection but I the subview isn't defaulting correctly (unless I'm on the french side).